# SkipInvalidSource when using msdeploy to publish my MVC site

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have used Visual studio to publish my site to a .zip file using web deploy package.

Everything was created ok. I got a .zip file, .cmd and .xml file.

I copied these files to the PC I want to publish them on. I created a new site name matching the one I gave during creating the package in IIS.

I ran this command line:

```
VisitorPortal.deploy.cmd /Y
```

But I get this error:

```
Warning: Skipping source dirPath  (Z:\workspace\VisitorPortal\VisitorPortal\obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp) because of rule SkipInvalidSource.
The Zip package 'C:\Users\BioDemo\Desktop\VisitorPortal.zip' could not be loaded.
```

And nothing is installed. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The .cmd and .zip files need to be in the same folder on the remote machine and then open a CMD console, traverse to the folder where the .cmd is located and then run the .cmd.